# Python : loop making variable

Tags: python

I'm trying to do a simple python program able to print the right variable depend of the incremented value.

```
a1 = 'hiya'
a2 = 'i love cats'

lignenum = 2
incremented_value = 1
while incremented_value <= lignenum:
    print(a, incremented_value) 
     incremented_value += 1
```

i want my program to render :

'hiya'
'i love cats'

Thanks for reading me

Comment: Where is `a` and `p` defined?

Comment: sorry p is incremented value

Comment: My true program have many more variable to print ^^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a list with this values you would like to print, and then access them according to their index-value.
That is:

```
arguments = ['hiya','i love cats']
lignenum = 1
incremented_value = 0
while incremented_value <= lignenum:
    print(arguments[incremented_value]) 
    incremented_value += 1
```

This prints:

```
hiya
i love cats
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a list and iterate btween 0 and the length of the list.  There are better ways to do this but a simple solution is below

```py
a = []
a.append('hiya')
a.append('i love cats')

lignenum = len(a)
incremented_value = 0
while incremented_value <= lignenum:
    print(a[incremented_value]) 
     incremented_value += 1
```